Isekai manga about a guy who dies, standing in line to reincarnate, asked by someone to help assassinate someone
Isekai black & white Japanese manga 100%.
The main character (MC) dies, is standing in line in the afterlife. Helps someone who is being bullied (by other dead people/ghosts).
A 3rd party noble comes along and asks him for help to get revenge. So the MC gets put into this guy's body, and he takes revenge, and the noble's soul disappears. The daughter of the man he kills gets locked up. But the MC goes to rescue her. Then they fight a swordsman, but run away.
Probably only 10 chapters or so.

super annoying i thought it had a skill board . searching for skill board isekai got me nowhere. then i though ok maybe it was a skill tree. its actually both skill board and skill tree in this manga. but google still wouldnt tell me!

"Undetectable Strongest Job Rule Breaker"
search used was: isekai murders a count manga site:www.reddit.com
